# What differences are there between a new and a refurbished iPhone?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone's lcd is crashed last night and I want to get a new one. I just wanted to know what people's though are on normal iPhone vs refurb iPhone. What's the real difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a refurb from Apple then it will come with the same warranty as a new phone. It is not a scratch n dent type phone, but will look and feel new.

Not 100% about getting one from a provider like AT&T or Verizon, but I think they will also provide a full warranty.

Comment: I've never had a quality issue with Apple refurbished product. I have seen wild quality variations with carrier refurbished equipment up to and including still having the previous customer's email, apps and content still loaded on the device. I would add - just ask the person offering you a refurbished item where it was tested, how quality control works and how it affects your warranty.

Comment: I asked them about the warranty they said refurb phones have 90 days of warranty as opposed on 1 year for normal phones.

Answer (score 1):

I got a refurb phone ~10 months ago. From my experience, the battery degradation was much quicker than a normal phone. I feel that the phone was used for a while they fixed it but the battery was used.

Overall, it does not worth the 50$ difference to get a cheap refurbished phone.